# MySQL Joined SELECT COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to select results across several tables, but I only want to return rows based on the `COUNT()` result of joined `SELECT` query.

Here's how the query looks at the moment:

```
SELECT `s`.`venue_id` AS `id`,
       CONCAT(`u`.`First_name`, ' ', `u`.`Surname`) AS `user_name`,
       `u`.`avatar` AS `avatar`,
       `u`.`facebookId` AS `fid`,
       `x`.`imgs` AS `num_imgs`
       FROM `new_shortlists_venues` `s`
       INNER JOIN `new_shortlists` ON `new_shortlists`.`id` = `s`.`list_id`
       INNER JOIN `users` `u` ON `u`.`id` = `new_shortlists`.`bride_id`
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `listing_id`, COUNT(*) `imgs` FROM `listingsImages`) `x` ON `s`.`venue_id` = `x`.`listing_id`
       WHERE `new_shortlists`.`venues` > 4
       AND `new_shortlists`.`bride_id` != 0
       GROUP BY `s`.`list_id`
       ORDER BY `s`.`date_added` DESC
       LIMIT 6
```

For some reason, the query returns `NULL` for `num_imgs`. Essentially, I'd like to select only records which have at least 4 records in the `listingsImages` table.

Please note that this is for a legacy system, and I didn't design the DB! As a result, I have now option to change the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left off the `GROUP BY` of your subquery.  Your current query is returning `COUNT(*)` associated with a random `listing_id`.  Add `GROUP BY listing_id` and you should return the correct counts.

```
SELECT `s`.`venue_id` AS `id`,
   CONCAT(`u`.`First_name`, ' ', `u`.`Surname`) AS `user_name`,
   `u`.`avatar` AS `avatar`,
   `u`.`facebookId` AS `fid`,
   `x`.`imgs` AS `num_imgs`
   FROM `new_shortlists_venues` `s`
       INNER JOIN `new_shortlists` ON `new_shortlists`.`id` = `s`.`list_id`
       INNER JOIN `users` `u` ON `u`.`id` = `new_shortlists`.`bride_id`
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `listing_id`, COUNT(*) `imgs` 
                  FROM `listingsImages` 
                  GROUP BY `listing_id`) `x` ON `s`.`venue_id` = `x`.`listing_id`
   WHERE `new_shortlists`.`venues` > 4
       AND `new_shortlists`.`bride_id` != 0
   GROUP BY `s`.`list_id`
   ORDER BY `s`.`date_added` DESC
   LIMIT 6
```

And to return those with at least 4 records, just add that constraint to your `WHERE` criteria:

```
AND `x`.`imgs` >= 4
```

Comment: @BenM -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This might be the culprit:

```
ON `s`.`venue_id` = `x`.`listing_id`
```